# Find second option/Assess duplicates in Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I am currently trying to use power query as an advanced index-match/ Vlookup function to reduce lag.  I have a data set that is essentially the following

[image: Source Table]

I am in need of assistance to get the following output:

[image: Desired output]

The goal is to have ALL of the IDs present with distinct confirmation numbers, The issue in doing a simple 'remove duplicates' action causes either a loss of ID numbers OR duplicate confirmation numbers.

Attempted the following:
Original Table

[image: Source Table1]

Then removed duplicates from CCTRANS Column:

[image: Remove Duplicate CCTRANS]

But this creates 2 transactions with identical confirmations, i need unique transaction IDS AND unique Confirmation numbers.

Other attempt - Remove duplicate confirmation numbers:

[image: Remove duplicate confirmation]

But this creates an issue of duplicate trans ID to a single confirmation number

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Made edits in post^

Comment: Will there ever be more than two values per ID?

Comment: Yes, A **cctrans** value has multiple **Table1.Confirmation** values associated to it. and vice-versa.

Comment: If an ID has five confirmation numbers associated, which one do you want to pick?

Comment: The problem is I have 5 confirmation numbers and 5 id numbers all in a many-to-many relationship.  I want the transactions to select the a confirmation number that hasn't been used.

Comment: For me, VBA would be a much simpler method of accomplishing this task. But if you insist on PQ, I'll keep looking at it and see if I can come up with something.

Comment: I just don't know anything about VBA and am more familiar with power query. I am open to any solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar enough with Power Query to come up with a useful solution.  But, if you like, here is a VBA solution.

It assumes:

- your data is in a Table named `Table1` on worksheet `Sheet1`, but there are many other ways of locating the data
- The results will be written a few columns over form the two columns of source data on the same worksheet.  Again this can altered to suit.

**Algorithm**

- Create a unique list of `CC Trans`
- Create a unique list of `Confirmation`
- Collect all the `Confirmation` that are associate with each `CC Trans`
- Assess if a `Confirmation` in the list is available (in the general `Confirmation` dictionary and, if it is, assign it to that `CC Trans` and remove it from the list of available `Confirmations`

  - *If we run into a problem here, we may want to sort the `CC Trans` by number of associated `Confirmation` (ascending) and then do the assignments. This will minimize the chance of using up available confirmation numbers.*
  - ***Edit:** Code below modified to include a sorting regimen to handle problem of potentially using up available confirmation numbers when others might be available. I used a `QuickSort` routine but others can be used instead*

> Enter the following into a regular module.

> Be sure to Set the Reference as indicated in the notes.

```
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Option Explicit
Sub combine()
    Dim LO As ListObject 'assumes your data is in a Table
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, vSrc As Variant
    Dim wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range 'location of results
    
    Dim dCC As Dictionary, dConf As Dictionary, dCConf As Dictionary
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, vKey As Variant, Item As Variant
    
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 5)
    
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
With wsSrc
    Set LO = .ListObjects("Table1") 'or whatever
    vSrc = LO.DataBodyRange 'processing much faster using VBA arrays
End With

'get unique list of confirmations
Set dConf = New Dictionary
    dConf.CompareMode = TextCompare
    For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc)
        vKey = vSrc(I, 2)
        If Not dConf.Exists(vKey) Then _
            dConf.Add key:=vKey, Item:=""
    Next I
    
'with unique list of CC Trans, with collection of confirmation numbers
Set dCC = New Dictionary
    For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc)
        vKey = vSrc(I, 1)
        If Not dCC.Exists(vKey) Then
            Set dCConf = New Dictionary
                dCConf.CompareMode = TextCompare
                dCConf.Add vSrc(I, 2), vSrc(I, 2)
                dCC.Add key:=vKey, Item:=dCConf
        Else
            If Not dCC(vKey).Exists(vSrc(I, 2)) Then _
                dCC(vKey).Add vSrc(I, 2), vSrc(I, 2)
        End If
    Next I
        
'create results array
ReDim vres(0 To dCC.Count, 1 To 3)

'headers
    vres(0, 1) = "CC Trans"
    vres(0, 2) = "Confirmation"
    vres(0, 3) = "Merged"

'Sort by number of confirms
Dim vKeys As Variant
vKeys = sortByColCount(dCC)

I = 0
'Ensure no duplicate confirms with ID
For Each vKey In vKeys
    I = I + 1
    vres(I, 1) = vKey
    For Each Item In dCC(vKey)
        If dConf.Exists(Item) Then
            vres(I, 2) = Item
            vres(I, 3) = vres(I, 1) & ":" & vres(I, 2)
            dConf.Remove Item
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Item
Next vKey
        
'write and format the results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vres, 1) + 1, UBound(vres, 2))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vres
    .Sort key1:=.Cells(1, 1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    .Style = "Output" 'NOTE: not internationally aware, so you may need to change this
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

    
End Sub

Function sortByColCount(d As Dictionary)
    Dim v(), vKey, I As Long
    Dim vTemp()
    
'create array to sort
ReDim v(1 To d.Count, 1 To 2)

'col1 = count, col2 = key
I = 0
For Each vKey In d.Keys
    I = I + 1
    v(I, 1) = d(vKey).Count
    v(I, 2) = vKey
Next vKey
            
QuickSortArray v, , , 1

ReDim vTemp(1 To UBound(v))
For I = 1 To UBound(v)
    vTemp(I) = v(I, 2)
Next I

sortByColCount = vTemp
                
End Function

Public Sub QuickSortArray(ByRef SortArray As Variant, Optional lngMin As Long = -1, Optional lngMax As Long = -1, Optional lngColumn As Long = 0)
    On Error Resume Next

    'Sort a 2-Dimensional array

    ' SampleUsage: sort arrData by the contents of column 3
    '
    '   QuickSortArray arrData, , , 3

    '
    'Posted by Jim Rech 10/20/98 Excel.Programming

    'Modifications, Nigel Heffernan:

    '       ' Escape failed comparison with empty variant
    '       ' Defensive coding: check inputs

    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim varMid As Variant
    Dim arrRowTemp As Variant
    Dim lngColTemp As Long

    If IsEmpty(SortArray) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If InStr(TypeName(SortArray), "()") < 1 Then  'IsArray() is somewhat broken: Look for brackets in the type name
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If lngMin = -1 Then
        lngMin = LBound(SortArray, 1)
    End If
    If lngMax = -1 Then
        lngMax = UBound(SortArray, 1)
    End If
    If lngMin >= lngMax Then    ' no sorting required
        Exit Sub
    End If

    I = lngMin
    J = lngMax

    varMid = Empty
    varMid = SortArray((lngMin + lngMax) \ 2, lngColumn)

    ' We  send 'Empty' and invalid data items to the end of the list:
    If IsObject(varMid) Then  ' note that we don't check isObject(SortArray(n)) - varMid *might* pick up a valid default member or property
        I = lngMax
        J = lngMin
    ElseIf IsEmpty(varMid) Then
        I = lngMax
        J = lngMin
    ElseIf IsNull(varMid) Then
        I = lngMax
        J = lngMin
    ElseIf varMid = "" Then
        I = lngMax
        J = lngMin
    ElseIf VarType(varMid) = vbError Then
        I = lngMax
        J = lngMin
    ElseIf VarType(varMid) > 17 Then
        I = lngMax
        J = lngMin
    End If

    While I <= J
        While SortArray(I, lngColumn) < varMid And I < lngMax
            I = I + 1
        Wend
        While varMid < SortArray(J, lngColumn) And J > lngMin
            J = J - 1
        Wend

        If I <= J Then
            ' Swap the rows
            ReDim arrRowTemp(LBound(SortArray, 2) To UBound(SortArray, 2))
            For lngColTemp = LBound(SortArray, 2) To UBound(SortArray, 2)
                arrRowTemp(lngColTemp) = SortArray(I, lngColTemp)
                SortArray(I, lngColTemp) = SortArray(J, lngColTemp)
                SortArray(J, lngColTemp) = arrRowTemp(lngColTemp)
            Next lngColTemp
            Erase arrRowTemp

            I = I + 1
            J = J - 1
        End If
    Wend

    If (lngMin < J) Then Call QuickSortArray(SortArray, lngMin, J, lngColumn)
    If (I < lngMax) Then Call QuickSortArray(SortArray, I, lngMax, lngColumn)

End Sub
```

[image]